# Cookie available in cookie header but not from getCookies()?

Tags: http, cookies

I'm seeing some odd behavior with a cookie on the server side, and would like to understand why.

On the client:

```
document.cookie = 'test_cookie=' + '[AB]cd|ef-gh[IJ]' + '; path=/;';
document.cookie = 'test_cookie2=' + 'cd|ef-gh' + '; path=/;';
```

On the server:

```
headers = httpServletRequest.getHeaders()
// iterate and print headers

cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
// iterate and print headers
```

Output:

```
// Both are there on the header, so tomcat doesn't block it:
...
header: cookie: test_cookie=[AB]cd|ef-gh[IJ]; test_cookie2=cd|ef-gh


// Only one shows up from getCookies()
...
cookie: test_cookie2=cd|ef-gh
// no test_cookie ???
```

Why am I not able to see the test_cookie2? 
I could uri-encode before I set it on the client, but I thought '[' and ']' were allowed cookie characters?

Is there a more correct way to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to set the cookie correctly on the frontend:

```
document.cookie = 'test_cookie="[AB]cd|ef-gh[IJ]"; path=/';
```

Not the double quotes around the cookie value that contains the special characters.